# Using iPhone to connect to localhost running on Windows 10 Computer (No USB)

Tags: iphone, localhost, port, ethernet, ipconfig

I'm developing an API and I am hosting it on my desktop server running Windows 10 using `php -S localhost:8080 -t D:\Code\Projects\Website`.

I want to be able to use my iPhone to visit this `localhost:port` webpage without plugging my iPhone into my computer via a USB since they are on the same network. Although, my desktop does not have WiFi capabilities; rather it is using an ethernet cable plugged directly into my router. When I use this address on my desktop, it works fine and takes me to my `index.php` page.

If I open my default gateway `10.0.0.1` NETGEAR Genie, I can see my iPhone's IP is listed as an "attached device."

I added an Inbound rule to my Firewall (TCP, port:8080, allow access, domain/public/private enabled), but I still cannot use my iPhone to reach this webpage using `[my_desktop_ipv4]:[8080]`.

Would there be any security restrictions from my iPhone's iOS settings? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solution?